# how to perform K-medoids

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I've been trying for a long time to figure out how to perform (on paper)the K-medoids algorithm, however I'm not able to understand how to begin and iterate. for example:

[image]

I have the distance matrix between 6 points, the k,C1 and C2.

I'll be very happy if someone can show me please how to perform the K-medoids algorithm on this example? how to start and iterate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A bit more of details then:

1. Set K to the desired number of clusters, lets use 2.
2. Choose randomly K entities to be the medoids m_1, m_2. Lets choose X_3 (Lets call this cluster 1) and X_5 (Cluster 2).
3. Assign a given entity to the cluster represented by its closest medoid. Cluster 1 will be made of entities (X_1, X_2, X_3 - just check your table, these are closer to X_3 than to X_5), cluster 2 will be (X_4, X_5, X_6).
4. Update the medoids. A medoid of a cluster should be the entity with the smallest sum of distances to all other entities within the same cluster. X_2 will be the new medoid for cluster 1, and X_4 for cluster 2.

Now what you have to do repeat steps 3-4 until convergence. So,

5- Assign each entity to the cluster of the closest medoid (now these are X_2 and X_4). Cluster one is now made of entities (X_1, X_2, X_3 and X_6), Cluster 2 will be (X_4, X_5).
(there was a change in the entities in each cluster, so iterations must continue.

6- The entity with the smallest sum of distances in cluster one is still X_2, in cluster 2 they are the same, so x_4 stays.

Another iteration

7- As there was no change in the medoids, the clusters will stay the same. This means its time to stop the iterations

Output: 2 clusters. Cluster 1 has entities (X_1, X_2, X_3, X_6), and cluster 2 has entities (X_4 and X_5).

Now, if I had started this using different initial medoids maybe I'd get a different clustering... you may wish to check the build algorithm for initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

You have clusters C1 and C2 given.

1. Find the most central element in each cluster.
2. Compute new C1 and C2.
3. Repeat 1. and 2. until convergence